# Amazon AWSECommerceService returns SignatureDoesNotMatch when I add ItemPage paramater

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, querystringparameter

I can successfully generate a URL to perform a search, but when I add the **ItemPage** parameter, the service returns **SignatureDoesNotMatch**. I have tried placing the **ItemPage** parameter in different orders in the query string, but to no avail. Here's the format of a URL that works for me:

http://webservices.amazon.co.uk/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=FAKEBCCVNRFG2AXAAAA&AssociateTag=xxxxxxxxx-21&Keywords=games&Operation=ItemSearch&ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes%2COffers&SearchIndex=All&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2016-07-03T21%3A58%3A00.000Z&Signature=FAKEEEFSDFSDFSDFSDFDSFSDFSD%3D

I am generating the URL in a C# App, and testing it in Chrome. I have spent a few hours trying to figure this out. I would be very grateful if someone could help me figure this out.

Comment: One aspect of the design of signed URLs is that they can't be modified after the signature is generated.  Is that what you're doing, or are you generating the signature after adding the parameter?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael-sqlbot. Now that you mention it, it does make sense! I should be less lazy and double check the implementation of the signature generation code. It's working now! You saved me from having to use their SOAP API!